# rounding off small numbers in python

Tags: python, formatting

I have a table with numbers such as 5E-7, 10E-4 but the numbers are to several decimal points of precision such as 5.646273838E-7. I know I can use the round function in python to set the precision but since all my numbers vary I want to be able to round each one to say 2 d.p but still keeping the exponents in the answer. So I want 5.646273838E-7 to become 5.64E-7 and 2.38212538E-4 to become 2.38E-4. I was trying to use a method where I could convert my numbers to a string and then work out the string length so for 5.646273838E-7 if the string length is ~ 17, I set the rounding to (17-2)*0.5 and it sort of does the job for my data range. But can anyone suggest a better method?

@user545424: Hey that's a very useful thing to know and does the job well, except that my data is being read off a text file which has strings as well as numbers. The strings are the names of the objects, example:
Name      Prop_1      Prop_2
object_1  5.343e-10   2.574e-10

I then use the following code to read and display it as a table and save as a latex file
numpy.set_printoptions(precision=2)

```
    out=numpy.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=str,usecols=(0,1,2,3))


    col=zip(*out)
    tab=Table(col)
    tab.write('table',format='latex')
    print(tab)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> format(0.1234, '.2e')
'1.23e-01'
```

The [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function and the closely related [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method are what you want here. `.2` means "2 digits after the decimal point", and `e` means scientific notation. There are a lot of options; see the [format string syntax specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a numpy array you can use `np.round()`. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(4,3)
>>> a
array([[ 0.77600629,  0.76947092,  0.8145481 ],
       [ 0.08514862,  0.67965067,  0.90147548],
       [ 0.88886939,  0.57478246,  0.38501869],
       [ 0.57264822,  0.3376192 ,  0.55660758]])
>>> np.round(a,2)
array([[ 0.78,  0.77,  0.81],
       [ 0.09,  0.68,  0.9 ],
       [ 0.89,  0.57,  0.39],
       [ 0.57,  0.34,  0.56]])
```

Edit:

If you need to keep a certain number of significant figures and not just round, you can do it with `np.set_printoptions()`:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
>>> b = a*1e-10
>>> b
array([[  7.76e-18,   7.69e-18,   8.15e-18],
       [  8.51e-19,   6.80e-18,   9.01e-18],
       [  8.89e-18,   5.75e-18,   3.85e-18],
       [  5.73e-18,   3.38e-18,   5.57e-18]])
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because the OP wants to keep 2 significant digits, not round to a multiple of 0.01.

Comment: If you print something like `np.array([0.0012])`, you'll see that setting the precision still isn't quite what's needed, because when the display doesn't use scientific notation, things go wrong. Setting a formatter does the right thing, as far as I can tell. I'm not convinced this approach is the most useful, though, since you still have to deal with stuff like auto-summarization (you can set `threshold` to handle that), and it's global state, and printing a NumPy array doesn't seem like the friendliest output format in the first place. It's good to know `set_printoptions`, though.